# Image not resizing/object-fill to height

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a project to list movies.

I want every movie poster to automatically resize itself to be 375px. When I made a div-class for movie posters to try to format the height of all of them, [a blank space appears beneath images that don't fit the height.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwrAd.jpg)

After reading some similar posts, I began tinkering with the heights and object-fit properties, seeing whether expressing the height in pixels or as 100% would display the image to my liking, as well as playing with object-fit:contain and object-fit:fill, but did not find the image resizing itself.

I am stuck on what to add/modify to get the image to fill in the gap! How can I make all of the movie posters to have a uniform height of 375px?

**css for one movie entry:**

```
.movie-image {
  object-fit: contain;
    height: 375px;
}
.item-desc {
  background-image: Url("https://64.media.tumblr.com/a273ca5e593b171e3fb237974bf40c8c/7dfc5099f5485297-4e/s2048x3072/3f00eac237cd5d0db7ee1cb72fdf06b175db9679.jpg");
  height: 85px;
  width: 250px;
}
.subtitle {
    background-image: Url('https://64.media.tumblr.com/d3b90aee405195699e293f320c7da8df/9e2fb2468a7c651d-9f/s250x400/1952c00e74253264eb65fafbfc0a634a68b86704.png');
    padding:5px; 
    border:2px outset white;
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow: -1px 0  #000, 0 1px  #000, 1px 0  #000, 0 -1px  #000;
    transition:0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.info  {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  font-style: normal;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.footer {
  display: flex;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; 
}
```

**html example for one movie entry:**

```
    <!-- item two -->
 
        <article class="film horror action">
        <div class="movie-image">
            <img src="https://amc-theatres-res.cloudinary.com/v1579117614/amc-cdn/production/2/movies/3400/3447/Poster/p_800x1200_ResidentEvil_En_0802517.jpg" alt="media image"></div>
 
            <div class="item-desc">
 
                <div class="subtitle">resident evil (2002)</div>
  <div class="footer">
      <div class="usa"></div>
      <div class="info">
        <span>#horror</span>
        <span>#action</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

@alex you need to give styles to image ".movie-image img" and code will be as below.

```
.movie-image img{
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 375px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```css
body{
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.movie-image img{
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 375px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.item-desc {
  background-image: Url("https://64.media.tumblr.com/a273ca5e593b171e3fb237974bf40c8c/7dfc5099f5485297-4e/s2048x3072/3f00eac237cd5d0db7ee1cb72fdf06b175db9679.jpg");
  height: 85px;
  width: 250px;
}
.subtitle {
    background-image: Url('https://64.media.tumblr.com/d3b90aee405195699e293f320c7da8df/9e2fb2468a7c651d-9f/s250x400/1952c00e74253264eb65fafbfc0a634a68b86704.png');
    padding:5px; 
    border:2px outset white;
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow: -1px 0  #000, 0 1px  #000, 1px 0  #000, 0 -1px  #000;
    transition:0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.info  {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  font-style: normal;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.footer {
  display: flex;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; 
}
```

```html
    <!-- item two -->
 
        <article class="film horror action">
        <div class="movie-image">
            <img src="https://amc-theatres-res.cloudinary.com/v1579117614/amc-cdn/production/2/movies/3400/3447/Poster/p_800x1200_ResidentEvil_En_0802517.jpg" alt="media image"></div>
 
            <div class="item-desc">
 
                <div class="subtitle">resident evil (2002)</div>
  <div class="footer">
      <div class="usa"></div>
      <div class="info">
        <span>#horror</span>
        <span>#action</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```